# hibernate auto create in-memory hsqldb causes Sequence not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb, openejb

I'm using hibernate as my jpa provider and want it to create a 
in-memory hsqldb on startup using:
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

But for some reason I get exceptions like below in my logs.
Things seems to work otherwise. Is it a hibernate or hsqldb problem?

I'm limited to using jpa 1 so I'm using 
hsqldb 1.8.0.10 and hibernate 3.3.0.SP1

This is similar to:
[Internal HSQL database complains about privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805478/internal-hsql-database-complains-about-privileges)

```
ERROR - 4. Statement.executeUpdate(drop sequence DDS_EMAIL_STATUS_SEQ) FAILED! drop sequence DDS_EMAIL_STATUS_SEQ {FAILED after 0 msec}
java.sql.SQLException: Sequence not found in statement [drop sequence DDS_EMAIL_STATUS_SEQ]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.log4jdbc.StatementSpy.executeUpdate(StatementSpy.java:694)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.drop(SchemaExport.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1327)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:132)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:184)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:490)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:450)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.buildContainerSystem(Assembler.java:368)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.build(Assembler.java:280)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.(OpenEJB.java:125)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB$Instance.(OpenEJB.java:60)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:271)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEJB.init(OpenEJB.java:250)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.openejb.loader.OpenEJBInstance.init(OpenEJBInstance.java:36)
    at org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory.init(LocalInitialContextFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory.init(LocalInitialContextFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(LocalInitialContextFactory.java:42)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:197)
```

Comment: Still running into this issue?

Comment: @David Thanks a lot for following up. Yes it was still bugging me, but I now figured out what caused it to get printed out. See the comment I added to Pascal's answer.

Comment: Great. Just wanted to make sure you were taken care of.  If there were any features you wanted out of OpenEJB in this regard, just let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using an in-memory database, it's not surprising that a sequence, like any other database object, is not there at export time. But I don't know why you get a full stacktrace like this. I just tried with a basic test case and here is what I get:

```
16:27:07.708 [main] DEBUG o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Unsuccessful: drop sequence MY_ENTITY_SEQ
16:27:07.709 [main] DEBUG o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Sequence not found in statement [drop sequence MY_ENTITY_SEQ]
```

In other words, it "fails" silently.

Maybe you could try to extend the `HSQLDialect` and override the following method:

```
protected String getDropSequenceString(String sequenceName) {
    return "drop sequence " + sequenceName;
}
```

into:

```
protected String getDropSequenceString(String sequenceName) {
    return "drop sequence " + sequenceName + " if exists";
}
```

Not tested though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying this out. I now figured out that org.lazyluke:log4jdbc-remix:0.2.4 is the one that is printing it out. If I comment out the following from my log4j.properties then these stack traces dissapear "log4j.logger.jdbc.sqlonly=info" . I'm not really sure how I can get rid of this, maybe I can configure log4j to skip it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a technique I like to use to get a fresh in-memory database each test.

```
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
    p.put("movieDatabase", "new://Resource?type=DataSource");
    p.put("movieDatabase.JdbcDriver", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    p.put("movieDatabase.JdbcUrl", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:moviedb" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    p.put("openejb.embedded.initialcontext.close", "DESTROY");

    initialContext = new InitialContext(p);
}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    initialContext.close();
}
```

Basically, give a unique database name by appending `System.currentTimeMillis()` and rebuild the embedded container for each test.

Keeps you from having to cleanup after your tests yet doesn't require a new jvm for each test.

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in Pascal's answer the problem is with hibernate dropping/creating the sequences but the error should really be ignored.