# one to many the same class spring data (hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to make a relation one to many with the same class java using hibernate (spring data)

this is my code

```
@Data
@Entity
public class TemplateData implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private TemplateData div;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="div")
    private Collection<TemplateData> baseCSS;

    private int position;
    private String data;

}
```

and I get this error

```
HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table add constraint template data FK_y1mi9blsbc08tmwm9jgvdd1b foreign key (template_data_id) references template_data
ERROR: "template_data" relationship does not exist
```

Comment: Is the table in the database that your entity is mapped to called "template_data"? If not, you should consider using the @Table annotation, i.e. @Table(name = "my_template_data"). Alternatively, if you want to rely on the ORM to generate the table structure, you should check if the generateDDL flag is enabled in the ORM config.

Comment: I added this I still not working @Table(name = "template_data")
.

Comment: Can you share the table structure (the table name, along with all the columns and data types)?

Comment: this is the  structure of table in the question code
table is not created in my database

Comment: Humour us and give us a short description of your table, as the error makes it sound like it is not exactly called "template_data" in the DB, but something else.

Comment: when I made // private int order; as comment it works ?? what is this !

Comment: Have you joined them on your other table?

Comment: yes it works now ^^ thank you every one

Comment: Edit your question or provide an answer to include the new, working version and well as your broken version. Otherwise, this question is of little value to later visitors.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes this problem occurs when we use

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

You can fix this by changing the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to update:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

You can go through [this tutorial](http://learningviacode.blogspot.ro/2011/09/hibernatehbm2ddlauto-2.html).

[Mikko Maunu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118846/mikko-maunu) suggested that

> Combination of `create-drop` and `in-memory` database produces these
>   for every database object it tries to drop. Reason being that there is
>   not any database objects to remove - DROP statements are executed
>   against empty database.
>
> Also with normal permanent database such a errors do come, because
>   Hibernate does not figure out before executing DROP statements does
>   added object exist in database or is it new.

### Resource Link:

[Unsuccessful: alter table XXX drop constraint YYY in Hibernate/JPA/HSQLDB standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054422/unsuccessful-alter-table-xxx-drop-constraint-yyy-in-hibernate-jpa-hsqldb-standa)