# Spring data JPA with HSQLDB: user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

I'm trying to setup a simple Database with an article which may contains comments with Spring Data JPA. However as soon as I enable the comment relation on the article Hibernate throws an exception:

```
o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
[...]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.ARTICLE_COMMENTS
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
... 157 common frames omitted
```

My article class looks as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String abstractText;
    private String author;
    private Date createdAt;
    private int visibility;
    private int likes;
    private int views;
    private int commentCount;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> comments;
    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

And the Comment:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String commentText;
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

And the pom contains dependencies to HSQLDB, PostgreSQL, Spring Boot Starter Data JPA and Spring Boot Starter Web:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I remove the relation to the Comment List, it works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look like joining problem. If you will add @JoinTable anotation into your article class private List<Comment> comments. Its work.

You can check this example
https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-association-on-join-table-annotations-example

Comment: How do you create your database schema? You need to add the missing table to that.

Comment: Adding the @JoinTable Annotation didn't help either, still same error. I let Hibernate generate the tables (spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop in application.properties).

Comment: You could try the fix described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20698339/4663544

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property were the problem. Spring defaults it to `create-drop` for in-memory databases. However, in the current Spring Boot or HSQLDB or Hibernate version (or maybe the combination?) this seems to cause problems. After changing the value to `update`, it just works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The exception you saw is just a **WARNING**, and it really doesn't mean anything broken. If you use `show-sql: true` options, you will see this warning is actually cause by `alter table comment DROP CONSTRAINT XXXXX`, which is part of Hibernate creation DDL, and hsqldb doesn't have any table when this query executed.

Changing to `ddl-auto: update` has its side-effect. `import.sql` won't work with this option.

To avoid this **WARNING**, you could add these lines to your `application.yaml`:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl: ERROR
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was in dependency I provided.
I have a column `@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text")` and old dependency doesn't support this column definition. That's why I had to change

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

to this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It is absolutely fantastic how people can be this far away from the understanding of the simple things really going on. Even in a primitive cases like this one. Absotutely insane...
How did you manage to go this far from understanding?

Comment: It is different databases