# junit hsqldb spring integration version error

Tags: spring, hibernate, versioning, hsqldb

I am using hsqldb 2.2.8 version with

```
<spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>3.5.4-Final</hibernate.version>
```

these versions.

here is the error:

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found:

I tried to change versions of both hibernate and hsqldb but couldnt find a solution to solve this problem. Do you have any suggestion on which version of hsqld suitable with which version of hibernate?

Comment: You're probably getting that error because you can't connect to the database. Check your connection string.

Comment: Here is explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805478/internal-hsql-database-complains-about-privileges

Comment: I am using hsqldb-ddl.sql in <jdbc:embedded-database tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to use hsqldb is let hibernate create tables, using schema ddl and data sql files is not a good choice.