# Liquibase fails to import change sets for hsql

Tags: sql, jhipster, hsqldb, liquibase

There is default jhipster generated spring boot application. At the moment of generating the database was set to h2 and liquibase changesets were generated. Then the database was changed to hsql.

pom:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:hsqldb:file:./target/hsqldb/db/server</url>
                    <defaultSchemaName></defaultSchemaName>
                    <username>server</username>
                    <password></password>
                    <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.mycompany.myapp.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <logging>debug</logging>
                </configuration>

....
<plugin>
```

application-dev.yml

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
        include: swagger
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: false # we use Webpack dev server + BrowserSync for livereload
    jackson:
        serialization.indent_output: true
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        driverClassName: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
        url: jdbc:hsqldb:file:./target/hsqldb/db/server
        username: server
        password:
    jpa:
        database: hsql
        show-sql: true
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: io.github.jhipster.config.jcache.BeanClassLoaderAwareJCacheRegionFactory
    liquibase:
        contexts: dev
```

Console:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000001::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.JHI_USER (ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, LOGIN VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PASSWORD_HASH VARCHAR(60), FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(50), LAST_NAME VARCHAR(50), EMAIL VARCHAR(254), IMAGE_URL VARCHAR(256), ACTIVATED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LANG_KEY VARCHAR(6), ACTIVATION_KEY VARCHAR(20), RESET_KEY VARCHAR(20), CREATED_BY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT $ NOW[*]  NOT NULL, RESET_DATE TIMESTAMP, LAST_MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(50), LAST_MODIFIED_DATE TIMESTAMP, CONSTRAINT PK_JHI_USER PRIMARY KEY (ID), CONSTRAINT UX_USER_EMAIL UNIQUE (EMAIL), CONSTRAINT UX_USER_LOGIN UNIQUE (LOGIN)) "; expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ON, NOT, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, IDENTITY, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.jhi_user (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, password_hash VARCHAR(60), first_name VARCHAR(50), last_name VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR(254), image_url VARCHAR(256), activated BOOLEAN NOT NULL, lang_key VARCHAR(6), activation_key VARCHAR(20), reset_key VARCHAR(20), created_by VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT $ now  NOT NULL, reset_date TIMESTAMP, last_modified_by VARCHAR(50), last_modified_date TIMESTAMP, CONSTRAINT PK_JHI_USER PRIMARY KEY (id), CONSTRAINT ux_user_email UNIQUE (email), CONSTRAINT ux_user_login UNIQUE (login)) [42001-197] [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.jhi_user (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, password_hash VARCHAR(60), first_name VARCHAR(50), last_name VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR(254), image_url VARCHAR(256), activated BOOLEAN NOT NULL, lang_key VARCHAR(6), activation_key VARCHAR(20), reset_key VARCHAR(20), created_by VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT ${now} NOT NULL, reset_date TIMESTAMP, last_modified_by VARCHAR(50), last_modified_date TIMESTAMP, CONSTRAINT PK_JHI_USER PRIMARY KEY (id), CONSTRAINT ux_user_email UNIQUE (email), CONSTRAINT ux_user_login UNIQUE (login))]
```

Comment: Just a guess, but try setting the `hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect`.  I don't see it configured anywhere.  Related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3805230/3737815

Comment: I also see that the statement contains `created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT $ now  NOT NULL` and it could be that the `$ now` is the problem.

Comment: The error message you report is not from HSQLDB. It's probably from H2.